# how can we reduce the cost of temp table scan while feching count of records by using sql server

Tags: sql-server

here just i am trying to know count of records in the temp table and passing to another variable, so that it was showing in the execution plan table scan about 100 %

please find the below query which i was doing

```
DECLARE @tmpANHdr TABLE (
  hdrId          INT IDENTITY,
  CBFId          NVARCHAR(32),
  ACPT_REJ_FLAG  NVARCHAR(8),
  PROC_FILE_NAME NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @tmpANHdr
SELECT TOP 100 AHR_CB_FTS_FILE_ID,
               AHR_ACCT_REJ_FLAG,
               AHR_PROC_FILE_NAME
FROM   FTS_ACK_NAK_HEADER WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  AHR_FLAG IS NULL
        OR AHR_FLAG = 0

DECLARE @varRecordCount INT

SELECT @varRecordCount = Count(1)
FROM   @tmpANHdr

SET @varIndex = 1

IF( @varIndex <= @varRecordCount )
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'hi'
  END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a primary key (index) on the identity column and that might make it perform better:

```
DECLARE @tmpANHdr TABLE (
  hdrId          INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  CBFId          NVARCHAR(32),
  ACPT_REJ_FLAG  NVARCHAR(8),
  PROC_FILE_NAME NVARCHAR(50))
```

Also, do you end up using the table variable for anything else? Why not just do this?

```
DECLARE @varRecordCount INT

SELECT @varRecordCount = Count(TOP 100 *)
FROM   FTS_ACK_NAK_HEADER WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  AHR_FLAG IS NULL
        OR AHR_FLAG = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

A scan on a table variable with no more than 100 rows is likely to be pretty cheap anyway. The table scan operation might be costed at 100% of the plan for the statement but that is 100% of a pretty small number.

You can avoid this cost entirely though by just looking at `@@rowcount` after the insert as below.

```
DECLARE @varRecordCount INT;

INSERT INTO @tmpANHdr
SELECT TOP 100 AHR_CB_FTS_FILE_ID,
               AHR_ACCT_REJ_FLAG,
               AHR_PROC_FILE_NAME
FROM   FTS_ACK_NAK_HEADER WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  AHR_FLAG IS NULL
        OR AHR_FLAG = 0

SET @varRecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```